# unable to correctly use done in jasmine

Tags: jasmine, angular-test

My html uses an ng-template. The template is to create thumbnails.

```
 <ng-template #thumbnailTemplate let-option="option">

      <div id="{{option.divId}}"> <!-- top level div of thumbnail. This will have ids thumbnail-1, thumbnail-2 etc.-->
        <img id="{{option.imgId}}" src="{{option.imgSrc}}"> <!-- this will have width, height=80-->
        <a href="#" id="{{option.closeId}}" (click)="deleteThumbnail(option)"></a> <!-- the X button is created using CSS. This will have ids close-button-1, close-button-2. They'll also containn reference to the parent div id (thumbnail-1, thumbnail-2 ) -->
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

the `handleFileSelect` creates a `FileReader`, assigns call backs for `FileReader` and calls the `readAsDataURL` function to start reading the file.

```
handleFileSelect(files:ArrayLike<File>):FileReader|null{
...      let reader:FileReader = new FileReader();


      reader.onload = this.handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
      reader.onerror = this.handleFileLoadError.bind(this);
      reader.onabort = this.handleFileAbort.bind(this);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  }
```

The `handleReaderLoaded` method which is called asynchronously takes loaded file and processes it.

I want to unit test the `handleReaderLoaded` method. The way I am doing it is by checking two variables `currentImageAttachmentCount` and `thumbnailContainerRef` which should have been updated if `handleReaderLoaded` worked correctly. The spec I have written is thhe following which works but I am not using the `done` function here which I suppose is recommeded to test asyn code for jasmine.

```
 fit('should upload image if user selects an image', async(() => {
    let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(0);
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(0);


    let file1 = new File(["foo1"], "foo1.txt");

    let reader = newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("in timeout");
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(1);
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(1);

    }, 2000);


  }));
```

1) I want to use the `done` method but I can't figure out how to use it. How could I rewrite the above spec using `done`.
2) As I am able to test without `done` method, I am wondering what is the use of `done`?

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken that my spec was running fine without `done`. What was happening was `Jasmine` was just finishing the `it` spec without even waiting for the `setTimeout`. As there were no assertions to be made, the spec was being shown as passed.

The correct was is to call `done` in the async code

```
 setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("in timeout");
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(1);
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(1);
done(); //without done, jasmine will finish this test spec without checking the assertions in the timeout
    }, 2000);
```

I think `done` acts as a checkpoint in `Jasmine`. When `Jasmine` sees that a spec uses `done`, it knows that it cannot proceed to the next step (say run next spec or mark this spec as finished) unless the code leg containing done has been called.